# Will a camera that's repaired after seawater damage be as good as it was before?

Tags: repair, equipment-damage

I was using a Canon 1100D aka Rebel T3 for a quite long time.
When I was taking some shots near the sea, my camera sank into the sea water, which caused motherboard damage and lens aperture damage.

The showroom is charging a really huge amount for this repair. In that accident, both my camera body as well as lenses (18-55 and 55-250) were damaged. The guy is offering me a second hand 1100D at a slightly low price. Here are the options in front of me:

- Should I go for the second hand camera 1100D?
- Should I spend money on repairing my old 1100D? But it won't have any warranty!
- Or should I save money for a time and go for a new better upgraded version?

EDIT:- The repair cost is approx. $280. For the used 1100D he is asking me to give him my non-working model and $225.

p.s. Money is a big factor right now.

Comment: If it is repaired by a certified shop, then it should come back working as good as a new one; that is why it is expensive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The T3 is a very basic entry level camera. As you progress in your photography you might find that it is missing some features that you will want to use.

I would not spend any money repairing it as it will be cheaper to buy a used one.

My advice is to buy a used 500D/T2i, 550D/T3i, or even 600D/T4i. Just get whatever you can afford. These cameras have more of the features you will need and don't cost much more.

Answer (score 1):

Don't have it repaired if they will not offer a warranty on the repair - sea water is extremely corrosive and they might be able to get it working only for it to fail days or weeks later.

It would help if you could tell use the repair cost.

EDIT - 280USD for the repair - how much for the used 1100D?

Comment: I have edited the question and added repair cost